# Serve static files with Django both from CDN and local directories

Tags: django, python-2.7

Is it possible to serve static files both from a CDN and a local directory? 
At the moment STATIC_URL is pointing to a CDN. I have also configured the STATICFILES_DIR to serve files from local directories. Also django.contrib.staticfiles is in INSTALLED_APPS. However, if I say:

```
"{% static "img/some_image.png" %}"
```

in my template, Django tries to download the file from CDN and never tries to search it locally. Is there a way to be able to serve from both locations?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. It will always build the url from the value of `STATIC_URL`.

What you can do is put a flag in `settings.py`, so that if you are running on your local host, to change the `STATIC_URL` variable:

```
if DEBUG:
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Similarly, in your `urls.py`, you can add this check as well:

```
from django.conf import settings  # add this to the top
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

urlpatterns = ('',
               url(r'home/$', ... ),
               # your other urls here
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Further tips are available at the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) including similar code to serve media files (user uploaded files) during development.